# Need a detail explanation for ffmpeg colorchannelmixer

Tags: ffmpeg

I read the document https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorchannelmixer; but I can't understand the meaning of the example,

```
colorchannelmixer=.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131
```

Anybody can explain each value?  .393, .769....  why does it have 11 numbers?

Comment: I have given a most detailed explantion for your question, with the resault of getting ... a downvote! So, if you find my new answer helpful, please remove the insane downvote by upvoting it. Thanks. (Otherwise, I wouldn't mind about getting an upvotes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter accepts upto 16 values in the following order,

```
colorchannelmixer=rr:rg:rb:ra:gr:gg:gb:ga:br:bg:bb:ba:ar:ag:ab:aa
```

Each value can range from `-2.0` to `2.0`

What the filter does is apply four linear equations.

Suppose an input RGBA pixel color is `(192,64,128,200)` and the expression is

```
colorchannelmixer=.3:.4:.3:0:.1:.54:.3:0:1:.2:.5
```

So, the output R value will be `.3x192 + .4x64 + .3x128 + 0x200 = 121.6 => 122`

The output G value will be `.1x192 + .54x64 + .3x128 + 0x200 = 92.16 => 92`

The output B value will be `1x192 + .2x64 + .5x128 + 0x200 = 268.8 => 255`

(since `ba` isn't set, default value of 0 is used. Since the result overflows max value, it is clipped to max value of `255`)

The output A value will be `0x192 + 0x64 + 0x128 + 1x200 = 200 => 200`

(since none of `ar:ag:ab:aa` are set, default of `0:0:0:1` is used)

Comment: Thanks a log. I understand it now. But I still have more question on it. Why does ffmpeg use 16 values to specify it? if only use 4 values, it will be easier.  Take you example  (192, 64, 128, 200);   we set (R, G, B, A) = (x*192, y*64, z * 128, a * 200); so we only set x, y, z, a, and can get the final R, G, B, A..

Comment: That only allows one-to-one mapping. So input R can only affect output R. The filter's name is colorchannel**mixer**. Each output channel can be affected by all input channels.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the documentation in detail. The filter accepts 16 options in total. For each output channel (R, G, B, and alpha) you have four input channels (R, G, B and alpha). Each parameter sets the contribution of each input channel to each output channel.

If you don't specify the parameter, its value will be set to the default (1 for input color channels, 0 for input alpha channels). That's why it's only necessary to specify 11 out of 16 options if you have RGB video without alpha channels.

So, these parameters:

```
.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131
```

can be read as:

```
.393 → amount of input R in output R channel
.769 → amount of input G in output R channel
.189 → amount of input B in output R channel
0    → amount of input A in output R channel
--------------------------------------------
.349 → amount of input R in output G channel
.686 → amount of input G in output G channel
.168 → amount of input B in output G channel
0    → amount of input A in output G channel
--------------------------------------------
.272 → amount of input R in output B channel
.534 → amount of input G in output B channel
.131 → amount of input B in output B channel
```

The remaining values are set to their default, meaning that the amount of input alpha to the output B channel is zero. The defaults for the output alpha channel apply too.